# C# countdown (diff between sql getdata() and datetime.now) doesn't show

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Using mvvm pattern,I want to extract the difference between datetime from sql and datetime.now for every row(item in listbox) and see it in a textbox.
At the bottom of the code is the timer I made.. but it doesn't calculate correct and it shows the as CurrentProduct.ProductDateTime as {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}
I have binding in xaml to CurrentProduct.Productname and it works fine same as CurrentProductDateTime.  What do i need to do for this in order to work? Do i need to calculate the difference in constructor?

**Model, Product Class:**

```
private string _productName;
private DateTime _productTime;

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
public string Productname
        {
            get { return _productName; }
            set
            {
                if (_productName == value) return;
                _productName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Productname"));
            }
        }
public DateTime ProductTime
        {
            get { return _productTime; }
            set
            {
                _productTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ProductTime"));
            }
        }

public Product(string Productname, DateTime ProductTime)
        {
            this.Productname = Productname;
            this.ProductTime = ProductTime;
        }

public static Product GetProductFromResultSet(SqlDataReader reader)
        {
            Product product = new Product((string)reader["ProductName"], (DateTime)reader["_ProductDateTime"]);
            return product;
        }
```

**Model,ProductCollection Class:**

```
public class ProductCollection : ObservableCollection<Product>
      {

         public static ProductCollection GetAllProducts()
          {
                    ProductCollection products = new ProductCollection();
                    Product product = null;
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
                    {
                        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["product"].ToString();
                        conn.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ProductName, _ProductDateTime FROM Products", conn);
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                product = Product.GetProductFromResultSet(reader);
                                products.Add(product);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return products;
           }
      }
```

**And ViewModel**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Product currentProduct;
    private ProductCollection productList;

    public Product CurrentProduct
    {
        get { return currentProduct; }
        set
        {
            if (currentProduct == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            currentProduct = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentProduct"));
        }
    }

    public ProductCollection ProductList
    {
        get { return productList; }
        set
        {
            if (productList == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            productList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ProductList"));
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ProductList = ProductCollection.GetAllProducts();
        CurrentProduct = new Product();
        DispatcherSetup();
    }

    private string _showTimer;
    public string ShowTimer
    {
        get { return _showTimer; }
        set
        {
            if (_showTimer != value)
                _showTimer = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("ShowTimer");
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    TimeSpan Time = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    private void DispatcherSetup()
    {
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    TimeSpan dt = new TimeSpan();
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentProduct != null)
        {
         DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
         DateTime d2 = CurrentProduct.ProductTime.AddMinutes(10);
         dt = d1 - d2;
            if (dt > Time)
            {
                ShowTimer = dt.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the `return product;` line, can you tell us the values of all of the properties of the `product` (particularly the `ProductTime`)?

Comment: @mjwills its the first row in the database:`Productname "smthing"` and `ProductTime {8/2/2017 9:15:37 AM}`

Answer (score 0):

```
ProductList = ProductCollection.GetAllProducts();
CurrentProduct = new Product();
```

should be changed to:

```
ProductList = ProductCollection.GetAllProducts();
CurrentProduct = ProductList.FirstOrDefault();
```

*Currently, you are assigning a completely new `Product` to `CurrentProduct` - rather than one of the ones returned from the database.*

Whenever you add / delete an entry from `ProductList` - you will want to ensure that `CurrentProduct` is set to whatever `Product` you want the calculation to be based on.

Comment: it works partially, because now it doesn't update time remaining when i add products ( i have add, and delete methods in product class). could i let the `CurrentProduct = new Product();` in constructor and make in tick method  to load  products collection and make a new object product with the time remaining calculation ?

Comment: Do you set the `ProductTime` when you create add new products?

Comment: No, in database is set default getdate() for ProductTime

Comment: and how can i achieve this? (for updating products in itembox by adding with a window i use a mediator and icommand)

Comment: also i want the items to delete themselfs when they reach 00:00 and i need to calculate for all at the same time